# Como obter string de enum em um grid ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Tenho o seguinte enum:

```
public enum RegiaoEnum
{
    CENTRO = 1,
    NORTE = 2,
    SUL = 3,
    SUDESTE = 4,
    CENTROOESTE = 5   
}
```

E o seguinte View:

```
@using MeuDominio.Enums;
<div class="animate">
<table ng-table="vm.DadosParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" >
        <td class="text-center col-md-3" sortable="'Nome'" data-title="'NOME'">{{row.Nome}}</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-2" sortable="'Data'" data-title="'DATA'">{{row.Data}}</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-2" sortable="'Regiao'" data-title="'REGIÃO'">@{{row.Data}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

O que preciso é  exibir a descrição do Enum na coluna Região(Centro, Norte...) ao invés da valor do valor numérico.

Comment: Qual é o nome da propriedade que tem o enum da região? `row.Regiao`?

Comment: E de onde está vindo `$data`?

Answer (score -1):

```
@using MeuDominio.Enums;
```

@Enum.GetName(typeof(RegiaoEnum), RegiaoEnum.CENTRO)

Comment: Por que negativou a minha resposta? O exemplo acima funciona perfeitamente...